# wine desktop is clipping on netbook

Tags: wine

I have a windows program I run in wine that requires a desktop slightly taller then the vertical work space of my netbook's screen when I create the desktop, wine clips it to fit the screen.  I have to set it top all, grab it and move it up, press Alt+F8 to resize it.  Is there a way to stop it from clipping in the first place.  Running with out a desktop, still clips it but then I can not resize or move it.

Comment: If the desktop is partially moved off screen before the program re-sizes it; then Clipping does not occur. And then it can be grabbed and moved where it is needed. Of course this only saves resizing, both top all and grab/move still need to be done. So it is replacing a resizing with a quick grab and move. Only slightly better.  Can someone come up with a solution that either leaves it on screen without clipping or at least makes it top all automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from alt+drag to move the window up and resize it manually as a workaround, I do not believe this to be possible as it's the Windows application declaring its starting size.  You will see similar behavior running the application on Windows if you have a small enough screen.